# Why was this flag on a 'thanks' reply to a deleted +1 comment declined?

Tags: support, flagging, comments

I've just had one recent comment flag declined on a noisy comment.

This comment was a reply to a deleted '+1' comment, and said, simply:

> [@FrankL Thanks!](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/1477/how-to-optimally-make-a-3d-model-of-an-object-using-photos/1486#comment2055_1486)

When you go to post a comment, you see this:

[image: see blockquote below]

> Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. **Avoid comments like "+1" or "thanks".** (emphasis mine)

And [Jeff Atwood said to flag these](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/15292/294691).

So I flagged the +1 comment, which was automatically deemed helpful. I then flagged the remaining thanks to that comment as 'no longer needed'. So... why was it declined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That action didn't appear in the moderator activity history, so I'm not exactly sure how it was handled. Regardless, I agree and have deleted the comment.

Comment: Probably a bit of short thinking on my part yesterday. Thanks for clearing it up!